# SQL3 ORA-22913: must specify table name for nested table column or attribute

Tags: oracle

I am trying to define a table in SQL3 of a type that contains a nested table in its type declaration. I do not understand why I am always getting the same error despite having tried several solutions. Here is the piece of code:

```
create type Composite;
/
create type L_PieceComposite as table of ref Composite;
/
create type Piece as object(
    name VARCHAR(20),
    containedInto L_PieceComposite
)
not final not instantiable;
/
create type PieceQuantity as Object (
    quantity NUMBER,
    pieceref ref Piece
);
/
create type L_PieceQuantity as table of PieceQuantity;
/
create type Composite UNDER Piece(
    cost NUMBER,
    contains L_PieceQuantity
);
/
```

In another file I use:

```
create table thePieces of Piece;
CREATE TABLE theComposites of Composite NESTED TABLE contains store as tab7;
```

But get the following error:

> ORA-22913: must specify table name for nested table column or attribute

Could anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is MySQL? The error message hints that it is Oracle.

Comment: yes we are using sql3 under oracle

Comment: Post definition of `Piece` as well

Comment: thanks for your answer, I just added it to the original post

Comment: What is this SQL3 tool you are using?

Comment: we are using sqlplus

Comment: So what's this SQL3 thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED..conclusion: we must beware of inherited tables.

```
create table lesComposites of Composite nested table containedInto store as tab5 nested table contains store as tab6;
```